# Can I use `render` function in coffee script in Assets?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

When updating a data from another web site I'm using ajax and want to show loading image.
I'm now using code like this.

```
$ ->
  $('#reload-lists').on(
    click: -> $('#list_owned').html("<div class='panel radius'><img src='assets/load.gif'/></div>")
    'ajax:success': (data, res, xhr) -> $('#list_owned').html res
  )
```

I want to replace `<div class='panel radius'><img src='assets/load.gif'/></div>` part with `render` function. But as you know this is not `erb` file, so I can't do it.

I changed file name `*.js.coffee` to `*.js.coffee.erb`, but it causes only a error.
How can I use html template file from coffee script in `assets/javascript`.

If I am in completely wrong path, please tell me how should I implement similar function like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use EJS Javascript Templates. It's like erb, but in Javascript.

- http://embeddedjs.com/
- http://rubygems.org/gems/ejs

Just follow this guide

- http://embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html#create_template

This solution is easiest. Just a reminder, that these EJS templates need to be accessible to the end user (aka /assets or /public). EJS templates are rendered on the fly and aren't in your Rails asset pipeline. If you are interested in pre-compiled templates in Rails, take a look at "JST templates".

(There are many other options: http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/ )